# Can you shapechange into an object instead of a creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph

I'm fairly new to Pathfinder and I was wondering if a character could shapechange into something like a door, table, or wall? If not shapechange would polymorph do it? I don't have a particular character in mind, I'm just trying to learn more about the spells.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [*shapechange*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/shapechange.html) spell is geared around continuous changing into a variety of creatures, and has a list of spells that it encompasses. It doesn't do inanimate objects.

[*Polymorph any object*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/polymorphAnyObject.html) (the spell which changes objects to creatures, objects to objects and creatures to creatures) can, though none of the spells that it can replicate are capable of such a feat. Turning yourself into a door with this spell probably wouldn't be ideal, because you would *actually be a door*, with all of a door's usual senses, intelligence and other characteristics for one or more hours (three hours for a wood/metal door the same size as you, one if it's larger or smaller, more hours if the door is made of human flesh...).